# Discard space above for the first paragraph

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

My paragraphs are divided by an additional space using `space-before`. However, sometimes I want to disable the before-space for the first paragraph, but retaining the attribute self.

Failed. Why? Can I get the desired result?

[image]

(1): Space is discarded at the begin of the reference-area (new page), ok.

(2): `fo:block-container` makes a reference-area, therefore the space should be discarded, but present.

(3): I hoped that a block with higher space-precedence would override the space values, but it is not so.

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<fo:layout-master-set><fo:simple-page-master master-name="bodypage">
<fo:region-body/></fo:simple-page-master></fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="bodypage">
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

  <fo:block background-color="green" space-before="1cm" space-before.conditionality="discard">(((1))) Alq</fo:block>

  <fo:block-container background-color="yellow">
    <fo:block background-color="white" space-before="1cm" space-before.conditionality="discard">(((2))) Alq</fo:block>
    <fo:block background-color="white" space-before="1cm">Alq</fo:block>
  </fo:block-container>

  <fo:block background-color="blue">
    <fo:block space-before="0cm" space-before.precedence="100" space-after="0cm" space-after.precedence="100"/>
    <fo:block background-color="white" space-before="1cm" space-before.conditionality="discard" space-before.precedence="0">(((3))) Alq</fo:block>
    <fo:block background-color="white" space-before="1cm">Alq</fo:block>
  </fo:block>


</fo:flow></fo:page-sequence></fo:root>
```

FOP Version SVN branches/fop-2_0